# How to override Variable Price in Cart of WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress

I am trying to find the solution of alter/override the price in cart for variation product. For example 
I have a variable product as color with different variants like red shirt, green shirt and blue shirt. Variant Red Shirt is in cart now so i want to alter the red shirt variant price in cart. But i am not sure how to override the variant price.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
}
```

I tried this above code it works only for simple product not for variant product. Can anyone give me a suggestion to alter the variant price in cart page of WooCommerce ?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = 10; // This will be your custome price  
    $target_product_id = 598;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        /*
        // If your target product is a variation
        if ( $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Add this code anywhere and make sure that this code is always executable.

After adding this code, when you'll call:

```
global $woocommerce; 
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(598);
```

Answer (score 1):

An old question but one I've been looking at myself so thought I would add my findings in case anyone else is struggling:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {

    $custom_price = 199;
    $target_product_id = 123;

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        if ( ($value['data']->is_type('simple') && $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id) 
          || ($value['data']->is_type('variable') && $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id) ) {

            $value['data']->set_price( $custom_price );

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add fees to it; https://gist.github.com/kloon/7906768